# Is a holomorphic function on the unit disc not vanishing at zero bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbf{D}\to \mathbf{C}$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disc. Suppose that $f(0) \neq 0$ and that $\vert f\vert$ is bounded from below  by some real number $C>0$ on some annulus contained in $D$. Then, does it follow that $\vert f\vert $ is bounded from below on $\mathbf{D}$ by some positive real number $C^\prime$?

Comment: Try $f(z)=1-z$.

Comment: Posted this as an answer to give you the opportunity to *close* this post.

Comment: @Did I do not understand the last line of the question and hence your example

Comment: @Tsotsi Hint: the answer to the question in the last sentence is "No".

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(z)=1-z$. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $